# Power BI Stacked Bar as Timeline with Milestones

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I need to show a Power BI visualization as stacked bar with milestones.

I have a list of activities, called opportunities, that have 4 dates associated with each one:

[image]

I need to show the events as milestones. The different Gantt charts in the marketplace do not allow stacking.

[image]

Is there a way to implement this?